# Python- While Loop with error handling

Tags: python

Ive been reading up on while Loops while learning python. The following works without error, however  if I insert `16` as value, I get

```
Insert numbers only
Your weight is 16 lbs
```

This is not correct

```
while True:
    weight_input = raw_input ("Add your weight: ")+(" lbs")
    try:
       val = int(weight_input)
    except ValueError:
        print("Insert numbers only")

    print("Your weight is " + weight_input + "!")
```

What am I missing ? I am trying to print out weight and if value = anything other then a integer then send error.

UPDATE

Decided on using tables with above . I get a error adding `"lbs"` Any help? `print(tabulate([[weight_input]+"lbs"], tablefmt='pipe', headers=('Weight')))`

Comment: The value of `weight_input` is `"16 lbs"`.  That's not a valid integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are adding `" lbs"` to the input which makes the variable `weight_input` `"16 lbs"`. You can add the "lbs" to the message that you display at the end of the loop:

```
while True:
    weight_input = raw_input ("Add your weight: ")
    try:
       val = int(weight_input)
    except ValueError:
        print("Insert numbers only")

    print("Your weight is " + weight_input + " lbs!")
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Sorry for dumb question. How do I end the loop?

Comment: You can use the keyword `break`. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) on control flow.

Comment: I did the following above. Decided on using tables . I get a error adding "lbs" Any help? print(tabulate([[weight_input]+"lbs"], tablefmt='pipe', headers=('Weight')))

Answer (score 3):

When you do

`weight_input = raw_input ("Add your weight: ")+(" lbs")`

You're adding the `+(" lbs")` to your input string. Try removing that.

Comment: `Try removing that` - Is this an answer that you know works or are you guessing? Maybe you should format this as an answer instead of a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the trailer=**(" lbs")** of raw_input first, then check if the input is one number by .isdigit().

```
while True:
  weight_input = raw_input ("Add your weight (type 'end' to exit'): ")
  if weight_input === 'end':
    break #use 'break' to quit the loop
  if not weight_input.isdigit():
    print("Insert numbers only")
  else:
    print("Your weight is " + weight_input + " lb!")
```

Comment: While this is valid, Pythonistas tend to prefer the [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-eafp) approach.